# Viewport meta tag not working phonegap

Tags: android, margin, viewport, meta-tags, phonegap-build

Viewport meta tag not working on phonegap build. There is white space between content and screen.

The meta tag that i am using is :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

It appears like this and is scrollable :

[image]

However it should be like this without any scroll:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Comment: I don't want a person to zoom in

Comment: Do i have to add anything to the css for it to be the same on all devices?

Comment: You should only do this if you have designed your app to work correctly at this scale. It is possible to render web pages almost completely unusable on mobile devices by adding this tag without any forethought. Make sure text is large enough to be readable and buttons are large enough to be tappable.

Comment: Yes they are large enough but when i use your method it scales to around 2/3 of the page

Comment: ok means your 1 thing is get solved. problem is scale now right?

Comment: @Hamza the answer is right. this should work. you must be doing something wrong. or may be some css issue.

Comment: Wait do i have to add anything in relation to this meta in css

Comment: Hi i have added a screenshot of the app

Comment: You have used perfectly same as what I gave to you? If it is then it should take device width height.

Comment: I got it to work on my phone. The emulator doesn't support this feature. Thanks a lot @Suhas.

Comment: ohh ok i thought you are trying on device only. Anyways good.

Comment: Hi suhas i was trying out the app on several devices and the app is actually a little larger than the display size.It is not fitting to the devices screen. Could you please help me out.

Comment: Suhas i have added screenshots to the question.Could you please help me out.

Comment: @Suhas could you please help me out

Comment: whats the difference between meta tag of question and answer?